# C: split 32 bit unsigned int into bytes and construct string based on results

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to split a 32 bit unsigned integer into an array of 4 bytes and then reconstruct those bytes within a string to be used as a file path

I am using bit shifting to split the int into a char array as follows:

```
void splitIntegerUsingBitShifting(int value, unsigned char *result)
{
    result[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
    result[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    result[2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    result[3] = value & 0xFF;
}
```

and so far have only been able to successfully create the file path using the sprintf command:

```
+ (void) storeIntegerStructureUsingBitShifting:(int) fingerprint trackID:(int) track
{
    unsigned char bytes[4];
    splitIntegerUsingBitShifting(fingerprint, bytes);

    char home[15] = "/rootdirectory/";
    char fullpath[100];
    char *delimeter = "/";

    sprintf(fullpath, "%s%d%s%d%s%d%s%d", home, bytes[0], delimeter, bytes[1], delimeter, bytes[2], delimeter, bytes[3]);
    printf("\"%s\"", fullpath);

}
```

I've read that the sprintf command can be costly performance-wise and since I am going to be calling this function thousands of times, was wondering if anyone had a suggestion for a better/faster way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: If you are using these file paths for opening files, the sprintf overhead is probably insignificant compared to the system overhead of opening/creating a file. BTW, I'd suggest using `%u` instead of `%d` to avoid negative numbers.

Comment: If you're using printf elsewhere and not just for debugging, sprintf will add negligible overhead.  If you don't mind HEX values, converting to HEX bytes is super simple, e.g. const char hexmap="0123456789ABCDEF"; chars[0]=hexmap[bytes[0]>>4]; chars[1]=hexmap[bytes[0]&0x0F]; etc;;;

Comment: DoxyLover and EkriirKe - thanks for your suggestions. I've gone with ikh's answer as it doesn't use sprintf and produces the output in decimal format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sprintf, you can use strXXX functions and itoa function. for example:

```
char buf[4];
strcpy(fullpath, home);
itoa(bytes[0], buf, 10);
strcat(fullpath, buf);
strcat(fullpath, delimeter);
itoa(bytes[1], buf, 10);
strcat(fullpath, buf);
strcat(fullpath, delimeter);
itoa(bytes[2], buf, 10);
strcat(fullpath, buf);
strcat(fullpath, delimeter);
itoa(bytes[3], buf, 10);
strcat(fullpath, buf);
strcat(fullpath, delimeter);
```

If you have still complaints, You can rewrite `itoa` *for only decimal* (It also may need to, because `itoa` is NOT standard C), and make your own `strcpy`/`strcat` return/receive `fullpath`'s length. (Each strcat finds `fullpath`'s length, and it's unnecessary.)

<strike>If you want variable string's length, you can use `std::string`. (I don't know its performance.. If you use this, you may need to compare the performance.)</strike> Oh, Your code seems to be Objective-C..

Comment: i found an implementation of itoa online (as you suggested, it wasn't available as a standard C function) and this does exactly what i was trying to do, so i'm going to select it as the accepted answer. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion: Split the value into nibbles (4 bit values) and use each nibble as index into the string `0123456789abcdef`, which will give you the hexadecimal representation of the string. Of course there's a "standard" function for that (though not part of the standard library its widely available): `itoa` with a base of 16.

Comment: Great idea, except the format string suggests decimal values are desired, not hexadecimal.

Comment: datenwolf - thanks for your reply. I've gone with ikh's answer as it produces the output in decimal format, but cheers for the itoa suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without library functions like by rolling your own version of itoa limited to single byte inputs:

```
unsigned char bytes[5];
char outstr[16]; // 3 digits *4 bytes + 3 delimiters + terminator
int i,j,n,d;

splitIntegerUsingBitShifting(fingerprint, bytes);
for (i=j=0;i<4;i++){
  for (d=100;d;d/=10){ 
    n=bytes[i]/d;
    bytes[i]%=d;
    if (n||d==1)   //remove this line if you want all dirs to be 3 digit numbers.
      outstr[j++]=n+'0';
   }
   outstr[j++]=delimiter;
 }
 outrstr[--j]='\0'; //overwrite trailing delimiter
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but when i run this for the fingerprint i get "//2/1/" held in outstr when i would be hoping for "7/71/234/131" (which would then be appended to the value held in home

Comment: I posted without testing. Minor bugs fixed.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to bitshift and copy individual characters.
You could instead just `memcpy` the 4 bytes you need to a `char str[5];` array and set the last byte to `'\0'`.

```
int val = 0xabcd3434;
char str[5];
memcpy(str, &val, sizeof(int)); // hopefully its 4 ;)
str[4] = '\0';

printf("%s", str);
```

Comment: That will produce a lot of unprintable characters and likely characters that are not allowed in a file name. -1

Comment: You are assuming the filesystem allows non-ASCII characters, including NULL.  Its not too portable on CPU with different endians but may not matter if OP is keeping it to himself never changing archs.  Finally OP doesn't want to use *printf.